# How to retrieve a single document using firestore connect in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a single document from the firestore but the id does not match and no record comes through when I am trying to filter and just retrieve that specific document using document id

I have no idea how to approach this further and I am stuck

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),

    firestoreConnect(( props,state) => {

      return [
      { collection: 'trains', orderBy: ['date', 'desc'], where: [["uid","==", props.auth.uid],["id","==",this.props.match.params.post_id]]}

    ]}))(DetailTrainView)
```

when I write this retrieval query in the page, it should return only that document with that specific id.
Thank you for your time.